# How to call a AVPlayer in XAMARIN iOS during notification instead of 30 second max duration notification sound?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I need to play a audio file which is 3 minutes length. But default notification sound does not play more than 30 seconds. So my idea is Calling a Avplayer 
which will play my desired audio. But i do not know how to call this. Can any one please help me. I will be very grateful.

I am attaching my notification method here.

```
public void AVPlayer()
{
    NSUrl songURL;
    if (!MusicOn) return;
    //Song url from your local Resource  
    songURL = new NSUrl("azan.wav");
    NSError err;
    player = new AVAudioPlayer(songURL, "Song", out err);
    player.Volume = MusicVolume;
    player.FinishedPlaying += delegate {
        // backgroundMusic.Dispose();  
        player = null;
    };
    //Background Music play  
    player.Play();
}
public void CreateRequest(JamatTime jamat)
{
    // Create action
    var actionID = "pause";
    var title = "PAUSE";
    var action = UNNotificationAction.FromIdentifier(actionID, title, UNNotificationActionOptions.None);

    // Create category
    var categoryID = "message";
    var actions = new UNNotificationAction[] { action };
    var intentIDs = new string[] { };
    var categoryOptions = new UNNotificationCategoryOptions[] { };
    var category = UNNotificationCategory.FromIdentifier(categoryID, actions, intentIDs, UNNotificationCategoryOptions.None);

    // Register category
    var categories = new UNNotificationCategory[] { category };
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.SetNotificationCategories(new NSSet<UNNotificationCategory>(categories));

    // Rebuild notification
    var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
    content.Title = " Jamat Time alert";
    content.Badge = 1;
    content.CategoryIdentifier = "message";`enter code here`
    content.Sound = UNNotificationSound.GetSound("sample.wav");

    var times = new string[] { jamat.Asr, jamat.Dhuhr, jamat.Faijr, jamat.Ishaa, jamat.Jumah, jamat.Maghib };

    int id = 0;
    foreach (var time in times)
    {
        var ndate = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "h:mm tt", null);

        var date = new NSDateComponents()
        {
            Calendar = NSCalendar.CurrentCalendar,
            Hour = ndate.Hour,
            Minute = ndate.Minute,
            Second = 0
        };

        content.UserInfo = new NSDictionary<NSString, NSString>(
            new NSString[] {
                (NSString)"time1",
                (NSString)"time2"
            },
            new NSString[] {
                (NSString)DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"),
                (NSString)time
            });

        var trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(date, true);

        // ID of Notification to be updated
        var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(id++.ToString(), content, trigger);

        // Add to system to modify existing Notification
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err1) =>
        {
            if (err1 != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", err1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Success: {request}");
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem. 
When a notification fires then WillPresentNotification() method hits and I simply call the AVplayer there and perfectly working. If u want to play sound via UNNotificationSound then not possible because that is limited by 30 second duration..but problem this works only in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You can't play an audio file instead of the `UNNotificationSound`.
There's no way to trigger the player's play method when the local notification comes. You could only configure the sound property using the code you post above. And the file should be embedded in the bundle resource.

It seems you are aware of UNNotificationSound: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound?language=objc. But I still want to remind you of the file's format and length limitations.

Comment: ofcourse possible and I did it. When a notification comes then WillPresentNotification() method hits and I simply call the player there and perfectly working. If u want to play sound via UNNotificationSound then not possible because that is limited by 30 second duration. Please do not discourage anyone if you are not confident. Thanks

Comment: @Md.RayhanKhan Please notice that `WillPresentNotification` is only fired when your app is on the foreground: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter?language=objc. If you want to do this when app is on foreground state, yes it can be achived. Otherwise, the answer is NO.

Comment: Hi Land Lu u were right.Thanks for ur comment. I did not noticed that it only works at active state. I noticed after ur comments. Can  u pls tell that when a local notification fires then which method fires at inactive state? if no method fires can u pls suggest me that is there any way to play my player during local notification fires?